# Odoo custom template

Tags: report, odoo

I am a newie in Odoo,

I need to print a template for customer visits, is not necesary to store records, the user olny see a input form with the quatity of templates to print and a button to do it.

What is the topic in odoo?

How I can do it ?

Comment: That's more of a functional question, which won't be answered on a programming Q&A platform. But let me answer it here in comment. Usually you don't have documents on nothing, but always in relation to a business object like orders. There you can print (download pdf to be precise) them right in the formular view. In the end you get a pdf which can be printed in a quantity of your decision (print dialogs always have this option. So what can you do? You can try to add a new report for example for business object `res.partner` (Partner/Contact). And now we got some programming involved.

Comment: And because it would be too much to explain how to add reports, try to look into the [official doc](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/howtos/rdtraining/J_reports.html) as first attempt. And some [more here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/developer/reference/addons/reports.html).

Comment: Thank a lot, It's what I was looking for